# Duplicate Step definition in cucumber

Tags: selenium, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

Why cucumber compares same method and gives error as duplicate step definitions

`cucumber.runtime.DuplicateStepDefinitionException: Duplicate step definitions in stepDefinitions.LogIn.SDLogin.inputUserCredentials() in file:/Users/nagarjunareddy/Documents/projectworkspace/eclipse/s360UIAutomationCC/target/classes/ and stepDefinitions.LogIn.SDLogin.inputUserCredentials() in file:/Users/nagarjunareddy/Documents/projectworkspace/eclipse/s360UIAutomationCC/target/classes/`
[image: project structure][image: navigation feature file][image] [image]

Comment: updated the screen shot.
1. Project Structure
2,3 Feature files
4. Step definition file
**User enter the valid credentials** points to the same step definition in the step definition file

Comment: If the file isn't too long; instead of using screenshots, please post your SDLogin.java code here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`glue={"helpers","stepDefinitions"}` instead of 
`glue={"helpers","classpath/stepDefinitions", "classpath/stepDefinitions.LogIn","classpath/stepDefinitions.Publish"}`

Refer this link
[Same issue on Github](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/1127#issuecomment-303486249)

Comment: A lot of effort. I would rather change the `@When` definition xD

Answer (score 2):

In the scenario you described, you have duplicate `@When("^User enter the valid credentials$")`. That usually happens when you have two similar steps and you copy&paste code and forget to modify the second one Especially since the IDE is not capable of knowing those two cucumber steps may be duplicates, you will get no IDE warnings.

Check again, you should have 1x `@When("^User enter the valid credentials$")` and 1x `@When("^User enter the inValid credentials$")`

Comment: If you see the the error which I got, isn't cucumber trying to compare two same SD

Comment: Yes. If the file isn't too long; instead of using screenshots, please post your SDLogin.java code here

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy I think you have an issue with your classpath as it is picking up same classes from two different locations - Users/nagarjunareddy and Users/username

Comment: No, second one I have edited. Actually the username was same. Forgot to Change in the first one

Comment: @Nugenrules you can find it here [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4SgyzyvwKhieWRzOThUcktDYXM)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the problem is in the Login.feature file which has the two same steps "And Click on Login". It's the problem about your domain-related design, but simply you can rewrite the steps into "And The invalid user clicks on Login" and "And the valid user clicks on Login".

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Just give a full path of your Step Definition file which you are running, in glue parameter value, so that cucumber will not get confused if there is same step is used in another Step Definition files.